# Javascript output to new window followed by PHP output

Tags: php, echo, popupwindow, document.write

I have a website that displays the results of sending email to the user via a popup window. The window opens and there is a delay before the confirmation message or error message appears. I would like to add an animation or at least "please wait ..." to the window.

The way it works is that window.open is called, then shortly thereafter PHP echo statement sends output to the window.

I tried adding a document.write immediately after the window is opened. That works to display "please wait", but it prevents the PHP script from being able to send any output.

I was hoping for a relatively easy solution that retains the present design. What am I missing?

Comment: **Never ever** use `document.write()`. Use inline styles to hide like opacity: 0 and then javascript to animate.

Comment: Sounds like the better approach. However, that is not my exact issue. I cannot get anything into the new window at all until I output from PHP. But because it has to wait on some processes, there is a delay in being able to do that. I just want instead of a blank window that stays there for 10 seconds or so before having its content displayed, to just display "Please wait ..." or even better a spinner I am thinking this whole approach of using the popup window, which dates from around 2004, maybe should be replaced with a jquery dialog.

Comment: Follow up: as stated in my comment, I was looking for an easy way to just put a "please wait ..." in a popup window that otherwise remains blank for about 10 or more seconds, and then displays the result of the operation. This mechanism has been in place since at least 2004. The better solution is to replace the whole thing with an ajax call and jquery for a nice dialog, and get rid of the popup window entirely. Pursuing that approach now. We have very few such popup windows still in place, and we should get rid of all of them.